# Problem calling multiple instances of a class in java

Tags: java

i have a problem calling multiple instance of a class that i have coded (Tree, TreeNode)
in the main method, the system would give the output c d j c d j even though both trees are obviously different trees.
if i were to separate both postOrder() calls(each called after the tree has been pushed in to the stack)

> ```
>     Stack<Tree> alphaStack = new Stack<Tree>();
>     TreeNode a = new TreeNode('i');
>     Tree tree = new Tree(a);
>     TreeNode newleft = new TreeNode('a');
>     TreeNode newright = new TreeNode('b');
>     tree.setLeft(a, newleft);
>     tree.setRight(a, newright);
>     alphaStack.push(tree);
>     Tree.postOrder(alphaStack.pop().getRoot());
>
>     TreeNode b = new TreeNode('j');
>     Tree newtree = new Tree(b);
>     TreeNode left = new TreeNode('c');
>     TreeNode right = new TreeNode('d');
>     newtree.setLeft(b, left);
>     newtree.setRight(b, right);
>     alphaStack.push(newtree);
>
>     Tree.postOrder(alphaStack.pop().getRoot());
> ```

the output would be a b i c d j.

Does this mean that my class is not being duplicated but instead being reused when i make new Trees?

Below is the code:

> import java.util.Stack;
>
> public class mast_score {
>
> ```
> public static void main(String[] args){
>     Stack<Tree> alphaStack = new Stack<Tree>();
>     TreeNode a = new TreeNode('i');
>     Tree tree = new Tree(a);
>     TreeNode newleft = new TreeNode('a');
>     TreeNode newright = new TreeNode('b');
>     tree.setLeft(a, newleft);
>     tree.setRight(a, newright);
>     alphaStack.push(tree);
>
>     TreeNode b = new TreeNode('j');
>     Tree newtree = new Tree(b);
>     TreeNode left = new TreeNode('c');
>     TreeNode right = new TreeNode('d');
>     newtree.setLeft(b, left);
>     newtree.setRight(b, right);
>     alphaStack.push(newtree);
>
>     Tree.postOrder(alphaStack.pop().getRoot());
>     Tree.postOrder(alphaStack.pop().getRoot());
> ```
>
> } }

code for TreeNode

> public class TreeNode{
>       Object item;
>
> ```
> TreeNode parent;
> TreeNode left;
> TreeNode right;
>
> public TreeNode (Object item) {
>     this.item = item;
>     parent = null;
>     left = null;
>     right = null;
> }
>
> public TreeNode getParent(TreeNode current) throws ItemNotFoundException
> {
>     if(current == null) throw new ItemNotFoundException("No parent");
>     if(current.parent == null) throw new ItemNotFoundException("This
>     is the root");
>     else return current.parent;
> }
> public TreeNode getLeft(TreeNode current) throws ItemNotFoundException
> {
>     if(current == null) throw new ItemNotFoundException("No left or
>     right child");
>     if(current.left == null) throw new ItemNotFoundException("No left
>     child");
>     else return current.left;
> }
>
> public TreeNode getRight(TreeNode current) throws ItemNotFoundException
> {
>     if(current == null) throw new ItemNotFoundException("No left or
>     right child");
>     if(current.right == null) throw new ItemNotFoundException("No
>     right child");
>     else return current.right;
> }
>
> public Object getElement() throws ItemNotFoundException {
>     if(this.item == null) throw new ItemNotFoundException("No such
>     node");
>     else return this.item;
> } }
> ```

code for Tree class

> import java.util.*;
>
> public class Tree {
>
> ```
> static TreeNode root;
> int size;
>
> public Tree() {
>     root = null;
> }
>
> public Tree(TreeNode root) {
>     Tree.root = root;
> }
>
> public TreeNode getRoot() {
>     return this.root;
> }
>
> public int getLvl(TreeNode node) {
>     return node.lvlCount;
> }
>
> public void setLeft(TreeNode node, TreeNode left) {
>     node.left = left;
> }
>
> public void setRight(TreeNode node, TreeNode right) {
>     node.right = right;
> }
> public static void postOrder(TreeNode root) {
>     if (root != null) {
>
>         postOrder(root.left);
>         postOrder(root.right);
>         System.out.print(root.item + " ");
>
>     } else {
>         return;
>     }
>
> }
>
> public static int getSize(TreeNode root) {
>     if (root != null) {
>         return 1 + getSize(root.left) +
>     getSize(root.right);
>     } else {
>         return 0;
>     }
> }
>
> public static boolean isEmpty(Tree Tree) {
>     return Tree.root == null;
> } }
> ```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is here, in the `Tree` class:

```
static TreeNode root;
```

You should remove the word `static`, and replace `Tree.root` with `this.root`.

Adding the keyword `static` causes the variable `root` to be shared between all instances of `Tree` in your program, which is not what you want.